# macOS starts downloading stuff when I turn on iCloud drive

Tags: icloud, data-synchronization, icloud-plus

After the latest update, I noticed that my internet quota has been completely consumed. Then, I realized that this was done through the cloud. Since I couldn't find a way to remove Documents and Desktop from the iCloud drive, I have manually deleted everything from the iCloud drive and kept a separate `Documents-Local` and `Desktop-Local`. Still, I see a lot of content being downloaded from iCloud on the Activity Monitor. But I don't see anything downloaded, as my iCloud is pretty much empty. I'm on macOS 14.1. It is really frustrating that they don't allow us to select the folders after this update.

Update: I figured out that iCloud tries to download the whatsapp backup even though WhatsApp is turned off under iCloud. This stopped after uninstalling the WhatsApp app on Mac. But still, I see a small consumption(3KB/s) though.